# Kotlin Multiplatform Compose ~ How to use events to control views

Tags: event-handling, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project where I want to use Events to control views.

The basic idea is this:

- Buttons & Co fire an Event when clicked
- These events get caught and handled by the responsible program components, which will in turn fire other events
- Eventually, some kind of `ViewEvent` is fired, which is subscribed to by the `ViewController`
- The `ViewController` then tells the program what should be drawn on the screen

In theory, that sounds like it should work. In practice, what happens is that while it gets to the point where the `ViewController` receives the event and reacts accordingly, the actual views are unaffected.

My `ViewController` looks like this:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.events.OpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.ui.main_view.MainView
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.ui.main_view.MainViewState
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe

class ViewController {

    private var mainViewState = MainViewState.TITLE

    init {
        val eventBus = EventBus.getDefault()
        eventBus.register(this)
    }

    @Composable
    fun draw() {
        MainView(mainViewState)
    }

    @Subscribe
    fun onOpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent(event: OpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent) {
        mainViewState = MainViewState.CHARACTER
    }
}
```

I debugged that, and was able to see that the `mainViewState` changes, as expected. However, the `draw()` function is never called again, and so the changed `mainViewState` never arrives in the `MainView`.

I've already tried making `mainViewState` a `mutableStateOf(mainViewState)`, but that didn't change anything.

Furthermore, I can't just call `draw()` inside the `onOpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent`, because it is not `@Composable`, and adding that annotation to the method causes the build to fail.

At this point, I am not even sure whether what I am trying to do here can work this way. Can someone please help me out here?

I have also published a version of the code with the current non-working solution here: https://github.com/KiraResari/ceal-chronicler/tree/event-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after worrying at this for several days, I have now come up with a solution that works.

Basically, the reason why it doesn't work as I tried it is that the frontend lives in its own little world, and it is very difficult for something from outside that world to affect it.

However, it *can* be done using delegates. Basically, what I called the `ViewController` in above is more of a `MainViewModel`, and it needs to look like this:

```kotlin
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.events.OpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe

class MainViewModel {

    var state = MainViewState.TITLE

    var updateState: ((MainViewState) -> Unit) = { }
        set(value) {
            field = value
            updateState(state)
        }

    init {
        val eventBus = EventBus.getDefault()
        eventBus.register(this)
    }

    @Subscribe
    fun onOpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent(event: OpenCharacterSelectionViewEvent) {
        state = MainViewState.CHARACTER
        updateState(state)
    }
}
```

The other part of the magic happens in the `MainView`, where the `state` needs to be a `remember` with a `mutableStateOf(..., policy = neverEqualPolicy())`, and the delegate needs to be set like this:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.models.main_view.MainViewModel
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.models.main_view.MainViewState
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.theme.AppTheme
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.ui.TitleScreen
import com.tri_tail.ceal_chronicler.ui.characters.DisplayCharacterSelector

@Composable
fun MainView(model: MainViewModel = MainViewModel()) {

    var state by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            model.state,
            policy = neverEqualPolicy()
        )
    }

    model.updateState = {
        state = it
    }

    AppTheme {
        when (state) {
            MainViewState.TITLE -> TitleScreen()
            MainViewState.CHARACTER -> DisplayCharacterSelector()
        }
    }
}
```

And that's all there is to it! Works like a charm, no extra libraries required.

Answer (score 0):

For my KMM project i use open source viewModel for KMM.
This one https://github.com/adeo-opensource/kviewmodel--mpp

I suggest transfer your MVC architecture to MVI and use this KMM viewModel to control your state as in usual android app.

Comment: It's not just an Android app, though. It's an Android/Desktop App. Thus, I'm working with KMP, not KMM. I'll definitely take a look though. Maybe it works for KMP too.

Comment: well KMM and KMP actually the same thing, so yeah it works on desktop too. You can share common code for all target operation systems at once: android/ios/macOs/desktop - for all platform that have kmm framework. More of that you can actually share even ui part with android/desktop using compose multiplatform.